# Syntax Highlighting themes for Monodevelop

Tags: themes, monodevelop

I am not too fond of any of the default syntax highlighting themes that come with MonoDevelop.  I have been trying to find a Vibrant Ink implementation (or really anything) but I have not found anything through Google.  Are there any good resources for finding pre-rolled themes for MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a blog today that had a syntax highlighting color scheme:

http://www.taimila.com/?p=1124

I sadly don't know any resources for themes.

Comment: The link appears to be dead.

Comment: Can't remember what was on the link, but i guess this is the site 

http://www.taimila.com/blog/xcode-color-scheme-for-monodevelop/

Answer (score 1):

I Use MonoDev Aswell. If You Are Looking For Somthing To Highlight User Defined Vars, Good Luck I Am Still Looking Aswell.

With That Said Go To:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Syntax Highlighting
```

Here Lays Your Default Themes. You Can Adjust Each One Or Create Your Own.

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 1):

[As of 2013](http://mikemdblog.blogspot.fr/2013/02/upcoming-color-importer.html), you are able to import syntax themes from two formats:

- the native monodevelop/xamarin studio `json` files
- the visual studio `vssettings` files

While you can find syntax themes in json (like [zenburn](http://undefinedvalue.com/2014/05/20/zenburn-xamarin-studio)), the definitive place is [studiostyles](http://studiostyl.es/) that will let you download tons of themes in vssettings format.

Once you have downloaded the vsettings file, just go

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Syntax Highlighting
```

And click on the **Add** button, selecting which format you want to import: `Color Schemes` (json) or `Visual Studio .NET settings` (vssettings)

**Et voila!**

[image: colors]

> **Note**: it seems that the old xml format is no longer supported